# Trying to get an AspectJ Pointcut to hit on Transactional annotation AND bring in variables

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aspectj, transactional

This is the code in question.

```
@Aspect
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class TransactionAspect extends TransactionSynchronizationAdapter {
   public TransactionMonitor transactionMonitor;    
   String message;

 @Before("execution(@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional * *.*(..)) && args(message,..))")
public void registerTransactionSynchronization(String message) {
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(this);
    this.message = message;
}

    public void setTransactionMonitor(TransactionMonitor transactionMonitor) {
    this.transactionMonitor = transactionMonitor;
}
```

I have created this Aspect bean in my spring config file.

I originally had this in the @Before block
@Before("@annotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)")

This worked. The places where I have the Transactional annotation would call this Pointcut. However I also need variables from the method that I and putting this aspect on. That's where the args(message) comes in. I have tried several different ways of retrieving that message (which is a String) but to no avail.

Would anyone know how I could craft this Pointcut to hit on the Transactional Annotation as well as pull in a variable from the method that I have annotated with Transactional? Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the JoinPoint to get its arguments[1]:

```
@Before("@annotation(annotation)")
public void registerTransactionSynchronization(final JoinPoint jp, final Transactional annotation) {

    // These are the method parameters, yours would be at parameters[0], but check first... ;)
    final Object[] parameters = jp.getArgs(); 

    // Your stuff here       
}
```

Using "args(message,...)" in the JP definition probably works as well, but IIRC the first parameter needs to be the JoinPoint itself. So it might be enough to just add that to the method signature.

[1] http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.html#getArgs()